# Override resource of the child module

Tags: amazon-web-services, module, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have rather extensive stack that creates VPC, Security Groups and Palo Alto Firewalls - 3 modules together.

```
main.tf
/vpc/
   main.tf
   outputs.tf
   variables.tf
/sg/
   main.tf
   outputs.tf
   variables.tf
/pafw/
   main.tf
   outputs.tf
   variables.tf
```

Once PA FW is done, I need to override route table to remove Internet Gateway.

What is the best way to accomplish so?

I am building multiple VPCs with Subnet and Route Table with associated route via multiple copies of "VPC" module

I am building PA FWs with bootstrap in multiple "PAFW" modules and need Internet Gateway in order to apply Bootstrap

Once "PAFW" module finishes, I need to override route with "0.0.0.0/0" to point to VPC Peering connection that is created in the main.tf that calls all modules.

So far I've tried:
- overrides from "PAFW" module, but cannot find a way to override resource in ../vpc module
- create a separate route, but it fails, as route with "0.0.0.0/0" already exists

Thanks for all help!

VPC Module

```
resource "aws_route" "public_internet_gateway" {
  count = "${var.create_vpc && !var.public_subnets_peer && length(var.public_subnets) > 0 ? 1 : 0}"

  route_table_id         = "${aws_route_table.public.id}"
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  gateway_id             = "${aws_internet_gateway.this.id}"

  timeouts {
    create = "5m"
  }
}

resource "aws_route" "public_peering" {
  count = "${var.create_vpc && var.public_subnets_peer ? 1 : 0}"

  route_table_id         = "${aws_route_table.public.id}"
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  vpc_peering_connection_id = "${var.vpc_peering_id_1}"

  timeouts {
    create = "5m"
  }
}
```

PAFW Module finishes Bootstrap with:

```
resource "null_resource" "check_fw_ready" {
  triggers {
    key = "${aws_instance.FWInstance.id}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "./check_fw.sh ${aws_eip.ManagementElasticIP.public_ip}"
  }
}
```

Comment: thinking about vpc private link more than vpc peering, maybe you can avoid the issue.